# Having Problem with HTTP-native Post request in ionic 4 native http plugin can't access my url

Tags: angular, http-post, ionic4

I am making a post request to my server from ionic 4, switched from httpclient to http because of CORS issues. Now the CORS issue is solved but I am not being able to send data to my server. Also when I try my api on postman it works just fine

The main problem is I also don't get any errors.

I have tried to debug it in every possible way, searched over the internet but found nothing similar to my problem.

HTTP doesn't get to my url even not getting inside the success or error block

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http
        .post(
          'url,
          postdata,
          {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        )
        .then(data => {
          console.log('i m inside http then block');
          console.log(data);
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('i m inside http error block');
          console.log(error);
        });
      alert('this is after http');
    });
```

Comment: Is the apostrophe before url a typo? E.g.   .post('url,postdata...

Comment: yeap sorry about that...

Comment: So you see the request being made in the network tab of the browser? Or that doesn't happen either?

Comment: that doesn't happen either. It just goes like blank nothing happens inside http block. it kind of moves pass it. I don't know how but I am not getting any error also so therefore it becomes kind of difficult to troubleshoot because there is no error.

Comment: I had a very similar issue about a month ago, I can't remember the exact details but it was a code error, just had to go back over it til i found the mistake I'd made. But with the CORS error fixed can you set up another method using HttpClient now and see if you have the same problem?

Comment: i have reviewed code many times, I couldn't find the error therefore I posted it online.
I have tried with httpclient but it always gives me CORS issue, as defined in documentation of IONIC itself. The problem is HTTPClient does not accept "Content-Type:'application/json'" and when I send data in 'text/plain' I am not able to get it on my server. So still stuck with such error.

Comment: I also have almost same kind of error in my camera plugin. I have posted another question for that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620150/camera-plugin-not-opening-camera-in-ionic-4

Comment: what backend are you using? You could tackle the CORS problem at the server end. Node, for example, uses the CORS library so you just add it via NPM and reference in the express app.

Comment: Codeigniter with REST API

Comment: Are you subscribing to the return of the POST call? This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793488/angular-6-unable-to-make-http-request

Comment: yeap, I am doing it, haven't missed it.

Comment: Can you make a simple stackblitz with the relevant code? I'm quite interested in seeing this resolved now

Comment: you know what, I created a new project and copied same code into it and it is working. if you remember I had also told you about camera error and I had given you the link to my question on camera, even that problem is solved now. Everything is working fine, same code but just created new project for it.